# Azure Dev Ops default permission policy

Tags: azure-devops

I'm working a small company (10 users) and we are using Azure Dev Ops to store our source code.

I'm trying to setup a default policy in order to achieve these requirements:

- all users should be able to read and write code to any "standard" project
- for some strategic projects, the master branch should only be written by some specific user.

I did not found any way to apply a defaut permission policy in Azure Devs Ops. Is it possible ?

I can accept manual settings for the 2nd requirement, but for the 1st it's too time consuming.

[Edit] Our Devops tenant is bound to our AzureAD tenant, if it can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I did not found any way to apply a defaut permission policy in Azure
>   Devs Ops. Is it possible ?

Sorry but for now it's impossible. We don't have the feature of default permission policy above.

> for some strategic projects, the master branch should only be written
>   by some specific user.

Now for those strategic projects, we can set [branch policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=azure-devops) on their master branches.

Combine the [Require a minimum number of reviewers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=azure-devops#require-a-minimum-number-of-reviewers) and [Automatically include code reviewers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=azure-devops#automatically-include-code-reviewers) functions so that the Pull Request created by **normal users** can't be completed if some specific users reject it.

**Note:** If the branch policy is set, only the normal users can't complete the Pull Request. The specific users(project admins or those who has [related permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=azure-devops#bypass-branch-policies) enabled) who have high permissions can still write to those master branch even though the PR is rejected. So I think it may meet part of your needs that only specific users can write to the master while others can't do that without approval from specific users.

Hope it helps :)

**Update1:**

If we create a new project, we have to add members manually. To make it more convenient, we can consider adding the users into a group in organization level:

1. Org level: In `organization settings=>Permissions`, create a `StandardUserGroup`. Add all standard users into this group.
2. Project level: Then whenever I create a new project，I don't need to add those members one by one.

In `Project settings=>Permissions`, I can create a new team (with read/write permissions enabled) and add the `StandardUserGroup` group as the member of this new team. Also I can choose to add the `StandardUserGroup` group from Organization to current project's `Contributors` group.

[image]

Comment: Not sure to get you. The only progress I see is that I can batch add all users to all projects from the user screen. When creating a new project, I still have to add every one manually. Or did I missed something ? Also, see my edit. We are using AzureAD, it it can help in any manner.

Comment: @SteveB Check if my update1 helps. As I know, if the organization connects one AAD or not won't affect the behavior. We have to add members manually after creating a new project. One workaround is to add the members in group in org, then we only need to add the group in project group to add those members.

Comment: Thanks Lance. It helps to reduce manual settings. I still feel it's a missing feature. I'll submit a uservoice

Comment: Glad to know it makes some help. And thanks for your coming feedback in our user voice forum ([DC](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html)) to make our product better -